# How do I use variables defined in one function in another?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    i = 0
    intInput = 0
    intCalculate = 0
    while intInput != -999:
        i += 1
        intInput = int(input("How many ounces of water did you drink each day?"))
        Calculate()
    print("You have drank " + str(intCalculate) + " ounces of water")
    print("For " + str(i) + " days")
    print("You drank an average of " + str(float(intCalculate / i)) + " ounces of water")

def Calculate():
    intInput += intCalculate
    return intCalculate

main()
```

I'm trying to use the calculate function to add the input each time until you type -999 and it stops the loop and prints the results, but I don't know how to return the values to use them in other functions.

Comment: you need to learn about passing parameters and returning values.

Comment: `intCalculate = Calculate(intInput)`

Comment: `intInput += intCalculate` seems backwards, surely you should be adding to `intCalculate`, not `intInput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass it as a parameter. For integers, this means that the function receives a copy of the value, so you can't modify the original value, unless you encapsulate into something mutable.

It's easier if you just return the brand new number and replace the original on the caller's side

```py
def Calculate(intInput, intCalculate):
    intCalculate += intInput
    return intCalculate
```

Then you'd need to:

```py
intInput = int(input("How many ounces of water did you drink each day?"))
intCalculate = Calculate(intInput, intCalculate)
```

Comment: Of course, `intCalculate += intInput` doesn't do anything useful; you may as well just use `return intInput + intCalculate`.

Comment: @chepner I left it intentionally to keep it consistent as to how the OP has implemented it

Comment: *"For integers, this means that the function receives a copy of the value, so you can't modify the original value"* -- No, Python **never** passes a copy on call. What actually happens is the function receives the exact same value, but it can't modify it because ints are *immutable*. And, beside the point, the function also can't rebind the name because it's not defined in the same lexical scope.

Comment: @wjandrea The OP is clearly starting their learning on Python so getting into specifics about if something is passed by value or reference is outside of the point I was trying to make, which is that the original value cannot be modified

Comment: @Matias Yeah true, I may have gone overboard :P The main point I was trying to make is that there's no copying involved, so that's misleading from an educational standpoint. You could simply say, *"For integers, you can't modify the original value, so instead you can return the brand new number [...]"*

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of thogoughness you *can* use global variables.

```py
intInput = 0
intCalculate = 0

def main():
    global intInput, intCalculate

    i = 0
    intInput = 0
    intCalculate = 0
    while intInput != -999:
        i += 1
        intInput = int(input("How many ounces of water did you drink each day?"))
        Calculate()
    print("You have drank " + str(intCalculate) + " ounces of water")
    print("For " + str(i) + " days")
    print("You drank an average of " + str(float(intCalculate / i)) + " ounces of water")

def Calculate():
    global intInput, intCalculate

    intInput += intCalculate
    return intCalculate

main()
```

***But please don't do this.***

Rather, as suggested, pass information via function arguments, or encapsulate state in objects where access to and changes to that state can be controlled via methods.

Answer (score -1):

You need pass the value to the function and capture the return. If you wanted to add the return from Calculate in the variable intCalculate you would want to do something like this in the line you call the function

```
intCalculate += Calculate(intInput)
```

And change the function header to:

```
Calculate(intCalculate):
    # Code goes here
```

https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions